# Finding a recursion relation

Tags: recursion, model, fibonacci

In my class we talked about a model for rabbit life that followed the Fibonacci sequence. The rabbits would start as a pair of infants and mature over a year. The mature rabbits would give birth to a new pair of infant rabbits. This led to the overall total pairs of rabbits that equaled the Fibonacci sequence.

I was also looking at this website that might explain this better than I am: [LINK](http://matheminutes.blogspot.com/2012/02/killing-fibonaccis-rabbits.html)

On the website I linked to they modify the model so that the rabbits die after 2 years and come up with a new recursive relation. I was wondering if it would be possible to find a recursive relation for this problem that was in terms of k, the number of years the rabbits live as adults (giving birth)?

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to try to give you a hint without giving you the answer.

now, you have your normal Fibonacci relation f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)

but for the case where the rabbits die, you have to subtract something too.  you have to subtract the number of rabbits that died.

Comment: I thought so, too, until I actually looked at the data. Then I realized that you only subtract it from the sequence when the year is one year after your standard age of death. When that is subtracted out during that year, the sequence continues with `Fn-1 + Fn-2`. So, it must be `Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2, n <> k+1` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here's data for rabbits living 10 years (note year 11 the first year infants die):

```
Year    New     Mature  Dead    Total
1       1       0       0       1
2       0       1       0       1
3       1       1       0       2
4       1       2       0       3
5       2       3       0       5
6       3       5       0       8
7       5       8       0       13
8       8       13      0       21
9       13      21      0       34
10      21      34      0       55
11      34      55      1       88
12      55      89      1       143
13      89      144     2       231
14      144     233     3       374
15      233     377     5       605
16      377     610     8       979
17      610     987     13      1584
18      987     1597    21      2563
19      1597    2584    34      4147
20      2584    4181    55      6710
21      4181    6765    89      10857
```

As you can see the number of dead rabbits follows the Fibonacci sequence, offset by 10 years. The total is still `Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2` when `n <> 11` (or n <> k+1), the only time it is not Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2 is during year 11 (k+1), at which point it is `F11 = Fn-1 + Fn-2 - Fn-k`. I don't know how to formalize that into a single equation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fooling around with this for a few weeks and have come up with the following for an arbitrary number of years, k, that the rabbits live:

```
F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) - F(n - (k + 1))
```

I'm only up to k = 6, but it seems to work except when n = k. In that particular case it seems to work if F(0) = 1. Once n > k, the formula seems to work (although as I said, for k <= 6 at this point).